# Array, List, IEnumerable, CustomList class cast to one and iterate threw them

Tags: c#, arrays, collections, casting, ienumerable

I am trying to figure out a way that tells me if a certain type is an array/list/ienumerable/collection ... I dont care what kind of it is even CustomLists so something like

```
FooList<T> : IList<T>
FooList : IList
```

or stuff like that.

I kinda hoped that a simple type.IsArray would be enough but sadly this isnt the case.

I need a way to check if its one of the above types and then check what the underlying type is, and than cast it to a Indexed based collection, where I can loop through the entries.

For a simple array this is all I need:

```
if (obj.GetType().IsArray)
{
    var elementType = obj.GetType().GetElementType();
    if (elementType.IsPrimitive == false)
    {
        var array = (Array)obj;
    }
}
```

This should work for every collection, there could possible be.

**Edit:**

As recommended below, I should as/is to IEnumerable but with IEnumerable I have the problem that the I cannot set certain object inside this IEnumerable.

With array I have used the method array.SetValue(obj, index) which works fine.

When I loop threw the IEnumerable and try to set one entry like this:

```
var list = obj as IEnumarble;
if (list != null)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        item = new object();
    }
}
```

I am getting the following message:

```
Readonly local variable cannot be used as an assignment target.
```

Comment: Not all of these types are arrays, but all of them implement `IEnumerable`, so you can start there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to cast it with the `as` operator:

```
var enumerable = list as IEnumerable;
if (enumerable != null)
{
    foreach (object item in enumerable)
    { 
        // ...
    }
}
```

However, if you need to modify it you have to recreate it. For example by using a list which you fill in the loop. Then reassign it to the original variable.

Or you could check if the type is a `ILIst` in the first place (like an array or list), then you can use it`s indexer:

```
var ilist = list as IList;
if (ilist != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ilist.Count; i++)
    {
        ilist[i] = "new value";
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I set a entry of the IEnumerable, I have used array.SetValue(obj, index) so far?

Comment: I am getting the following message doing this : "Readonly local variable cannot be used as an assignment target"

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this (... as IList) wouldnt work on a IEnumerable/IEnumerable<T> or CustomLists that only implement one of those or?

Comment: Or is there maybe a way to make a writeable .GetEnumerator().Current, maybe a static extension that does the job?

Comment: No, you can't edit `Enumerator.Current`. `IEnumerable` provides read only and forward-only enumeration over a collection. That's it, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, you could do a simple inheritence check for the enumerable interface via

```
if (FooList is IEnumerable)
    // We have a List
```

You can also use Linq and do a

```
if (FooList.ToList().Count > 1)
    // We have a List
```

But this would be rather unconventional.