# DeepClone issue with Arrays

Tags: c#, list, clone

I am trying to implement a deep clone feature and already asked some question:

- [IsPrimitive doesn't include nullable primitive values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973901)
- [Array, List, IEnumerable, CustomList class cast to one and iterate threw them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20975624)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978951

I am modifing the following code:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11308879/2598770

And currently I am facing the problem, that my original list also gets modified with "copied" objects instead of only the clone object, as recommended by the 2nd earlier question ([Array, List, IEnumerable, CustomList class cast to one and iterate threw them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20975624)). I have change the following code:

```
//Code directly from source
var cloneObject = CloneMethod.Invoke(originalObject, null);
if (typeToReflect.IsArray)
{
    var arrayType = typeToReflect.GetElementType();
    if (IsPrimitive(arrayType) == false)
    {
        Array clonedArray = (Array)cloneObject;
        clonedArray.ForEach((array, indices) => array.SetValue(InternalCopy(clonedArray.GetValue(indices), visited), indices));
    }
}
```

To a version that also handles, IList and not just arrays:

```
var cloneObject = CloneMethod.Invoke(originalObject, null);
if (cloneObject is IList)
{
    if (typeToReflect.GetGenericArguments().Any())
    {
        var arrayType = typeToReflect.GenericTypeArguments[0];
        if (IsPrimitive(arrayType) == false)
        {
            var clonedArray = (IList)cloneObject;
            if (clonedArray.IsReadOnly == false)
                for (var i = 0; i < clonedArray.Count; i++)
                {
                    var originalListEntry = clonedArray[i];
                    var clonedListEntry = InternalCopy(originalListEntry, visited);
                    clonedArray[i] = clonedListEntry;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

but on the line `clonedArray[i] = clonedListEntry;`, it doesnt just change the clonedArray but also the `originalObject`.

How can I prevent this, so that the clonedListEntry only gets set on the clonedArray?

Comment: Are you re-inventing yet another automapper?

Comment: @Dennis Dont think so, I just want to have a simple copy of my object thats all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new container instead of just getting a reference to `cloneObject`. For example:

```
var existingList = (IList)cloneObject;
var clonedArray = Array.CreateInstance(arrayType, existingList.Count);
```

You can then go on to populate `clonedArray`. In the existing code the `clonedArray` is just a reference to your original list (it's not even guaranteed to be an array!), so any changes made to it get reflected to the original as well.

Comment: But shouldnt this already be done by the line `var cloneObject = CloneMethod.Invoke(originalObject, null);` ?

Comment: @RandRandom: I honestly don't know because I don't see the implementation anywhere. But isn't the problem description enough proof that it doesn't clone as it appears to be doing?

Comment: Here you have a direct link to the source code https://raw.github.com/Burtsev-Alexey/net-object-deep-copy/master/ObjectExtensions.cs (its from the post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11308879/2598770), The CloneMethod does the following `private static readonly MethodInfo CloneMethod = typeof(Object).GetMethod("MemberwiseClone", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);`

Comment: @RandRandom: `MemberwiseClone` is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to make a *shallow* copy of its input: "If a field is a reference type, the reference is copied but the referred object is not; therefore, the original object and its clone refer to the same object."